# How to detect end of file using scipy.io.FortranFile

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io, scipy

I am reading an formatted sequential file output from a Fortran program. I am using the [scipy.io.FortranFile](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.io.FortranFile.html) class to do this, and am successfully extracting the information I need.

My problem: I do not know how long the input file is, and have no way of knowing how many records to read in. Currently, I am simply iteratively reading the file until an exception is raised (a `TypeError`, but I don't know if this is how it would always fail). I would prefer to do this more elegantly.

Is there anyway to detect EOF using the `FortranFile` class? Or alternately is there a better way to read in unformatted sequential files?

Some cursory research (I am not a Fortran programmer) indicates to me that if reading this using the Fortran `READ` function, one can check the `IOSTAT` flag to determine if you are at the end of the file. I would be surprised if a similar capability isn't provided in the `FortranFile` class, but I don't see any mention of it in the documentation.